# ImproperlyConfigured at **The included urlconf ****does not appear to have any patterns in it

Tags: python, django, url

I am working on a django project and facing an issue. The name of my main project is testproject. In **settings.py** I have :

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'testproject.urls'
```

There are two apps in the project too. One is **example**, other is **new**.

*urls.py* for testproject:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include('new.urls')),
    url(r'', include('example.urls')),
]
```

This is the **urls.py** of *example*:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from example import views
urlpatterns = [
    url('example/$', views.Example.as_view()),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

This is the **urls.py** of *new:*

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from new import views

urlpatterns = [
    url('new/$', views.New.as_view()),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

On hitting url "127.0.0.1:8000/example" I am getting the error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /example/
The included urlconf '<module 'new.urls' from '/Users/testproject/name/urls.pyc'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

But I don't see any circular imports here. I'm stuck. Please help me.

Comment: You say 'one is `example`, other is `new`', but the error message says `name.urls` which you haven't shown. It's really hard to help when you use made up variables.

Comment: Actually I have to use made up variables.can't use project name in an open platform like this. but my problem is same

Comment: What about the project's urls.py?

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 0):

In the project's urls.py try:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^new/$', include('new.urls')),
url(r'^example/$', include('example.urls')),
]
```

In the example's urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.Example.as_view()),
]
```

And the last one:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.New.as_view()),
]
```